# How to add a column of different length to a data frame in R?

Tags: r, merge

I have two DFs as following:

df1

```
ID Borrower
 1   A 
 2   A 
 3   A
```

df2

```
ID Borrower Category
 1    A        X 
 1    A        X 
 1    A        X 
 2    A        X 
 2    A        X 
 2    A        X 
 3    A        X 
 3    A        X 
 3    A        X
```

I want to get the third column of df2 and add it to the first df. The final result that I want to get is something as following:

```
ID Borrower Category 
1     A       X 
2     A       X 
3     A       X
```

I tried `df3<-left_join(df1, df2, by="ID", all=FALSE)` but is not working. This code produces to me something similar like `df2` (so ID=1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3). How can I add the column "Category" and get the desired result as presented above? Thank you :) :)

Comment: `merge(df1, unique(df2))`

Comment: Thank you so much :) The only problem that I face when using this code is that the elements of "ID" from df1 that are not appearing in "ID" of df2 are not part of the final result when I use merge(df1, unique(df2)). For example,if in my df1, the "ID" column has another value=4 (and the "ID" column in my df2 does not have any value=4), then the final result, does not contain ID=4 at all (of course, the Category column in this case would be empty NA since there is no info of ID=4 in my df2.). In this case, is there anything I can do to not lose the unique values of df1 in my final result?

Comment: `merge(df1, unique(df2), all.x=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have duplicate values in `df2`. You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
         ~ID, ~Borrower,
              1 ,  "A",
              2 ,  "A",
              3 ,  "A"
         )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
         ~ID, ~Borrower, ~Category,
          1L,       "A",       "X",
          1L,       "A",       "X",
          1L,       "A",       "X",
          2L,       "A",       "X",
          2L,       "A",       "X",
          2L,       "A",       "X",
          3L,       "A",       "X",
          3L,       "A",       "X",
          3L,       "A",       "X"
         )

df1 %>% 
  left_join(distinct(df2)) 

Joining, by = c("ID", "Borrower")
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID Borrower Category
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   
1     1 A        X       
2     2 A        X       
3     3 A        X
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dominik :) Adding function "distinct" before my df2 solved my problem. When dealing with merging in general, what is the difference between using the code left_join(df1, distinct(df2))  and  merge(df1, unique(df2))?

Comment: `merge` is the base R equivalent to `left_join` (which is from the `dplyr` package